# How to exit function in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use similar kind of action like `Exit sub` in MVC application and I am using c# language.

When I just type `return` its shows an error. Its ask for compulsory `ActionResult`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Validations v = new Validations();
            Boolean ValidProperties = true;
            EmptyResult er;

            string sResult = v.Validate100CharLength(location.Name, location.Name);
            if (sResult == "Accept")
            {
                ValidProperties = true;
            }
            else
            {
    //What should I write here ? 
    //I wan to write return boolean prperty false 
            // When I write return it asks for the ActionResult
            }

             if (ValidProperties == true)
             {
                 db.Locations.Add(location);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
             }
        }

        ViewBag.OwnerId = new SelectList(
                            db.Employees, "Id", "FirstName", location.OwnerId);
        return View(location);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want if sResult!="Accept"? Is it means that validation fails? If its true, then you need to add error message to ModelState and return View(location).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you do in your method, you could try that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Location location)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Validations v = new Validations();
        Boolean ValidProperties = true;
        EmptyResult er;

        string sResult = v.Validate100CharLength(location.Name, location.Name);
        if (sResult == "Accept")
        {
            ValidProperties = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ValidProperties = false;
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "sResult is not accepted! Validation failed");
        }

         if (ValidProperties == true)
         {
             db.Locations.Add(location);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
    }

    ViewBag.OwnerId = new SelectList(
                        db.Employees, "Id", "FirstName", location.OwnerId);
    return View(location);
}
```

By the way, there are many places to refactoring in this method.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is declared to return any type other than void you can not exit it with return instruction and you must provide a return type.  Returning null is usually the answer. In MVC however you might want to return something that will indicate to the user that something went wrong.